# Moving a div leaves a space where the original position was?

Tags: css, html

I have a div, which I move like this:

```
.x .y {
    position: relative;
    top: 163px;
}
```

Now that leaves a space at the size of the div where it was placed originally. Is there a way to get rid of that space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute;` instead of `position:relative;`... and then instead `top:163px;` use `margin-top: 163px;`

**UPDATE** You can use also, `top: 163px;` depending on what you are using it for.

Comment: Yeah, works ... but its too far right now ... how do I fix that?

Comment: I guess I can use left, since position:absolute would make it appear on different locations for different screens and resolutions?

Comment: could you paste the code you are trying to use? If you are trying to center it on a screen to be even for each screen size you can do this: `left:50%; margin-right:-300px;` Change the margin-right to whatever you like.

Comment: I dont want to center it, I just want to move it down from where it is without leaving the empty space, thats all.

Comment: Then to the div you want to move. Add `position:absolute;`. Remove any css from that div that positions it top, bottom, left, or right and just use negative or positive margin: example `margin:-100px 0 0 200px;`

Answer (score 0):

I guess `position: absolute` is not an option in most of cases.

Try to make it `float`!